# Minecraft & Hamachi IPs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, hamachi

I and a friend play minecraft, and with the recent 1.3.1 release we can now open our games to LAN ^_^

Or we can sometimes, sometimes we can't, sometimes we can, it's quite confusing, and we're not sure why it's happening.

See if I open my minecraft game to LAN for people to connect, it says in chat they can connect on IP:port. Sometimes this IP takes the form 5.xx.etc... which is my hamachi IP at the time. When this happens my friend also on Hamachi can connect as expected.

Sometimes however it says 192.168.0.x and he cannot connect, because minecraft is listening on the wrong network adaptor. This also happens on his machine sometimes. We're not sure why it happens sometimes and not others.

How do we fix or control this? We've had the issue on both OS X and Windows 7.

We initially had it trying to connect a macbook air to a PC running windows 7. Apparently Minecraft had picked up the virtualbox network adaptor and had decided to start listening on that, rather than the local LAN. Disabling that adaptor fixed the issue, but disabling the internet will render the Hamachi adaptor unusable.

Comment: Have you tried changing the hamachi adapter priority *(in XP, it's network connections --> advanced --> advanced; might be the same under Windows 7, try hitting Alt at the Network connections screen)*?  Also, disabling the internet adapter, starting the minecraft server, and reenabling the adapter could be an option.  Finally, you could try [tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net/) instead - I've never tried it with Minecraft specifically, but I used to have these sort of problems all the time with many other games (ex. CC:RA2, AoE) under Hamachi, but they all work perfectly under Tunngle.

Comment: Why are you using hamachi?

Comment: I see no reference to adaptor priority in Network & Sharing or in the adaptor list. Also I'm using Hamachi because my friends machine is ~2miles away from me. While it's unlikely I can run a CAT6 cable through a city center and under a river, luck would have it there's already a working Internet based connection =p

Comment: But it does apply to the general case ( Y u no use LAN, y u use inactive virtual adaptor?!  )

Comment: @TomJNowell why don't you port forward? Don't know how? Also, use the @ then my name so I get a notification :)

Comment: @AidenMueller Because setting up Hamachi is easier then guiding someone through port forwarding who isn't as tech saavy with multiple router interfaces, especially when in the future I may have an angry 7 year old when her machines IP changes for whatever reason.

It also doesn't prevent Minecraft from latching onto virtual machine network adaptors rather than LAN adaptors, resulting in a minecraft that can only be reached from a VM or some other obscure program.

Comment: @TomJNowell what's the big deal if an ip changes? You just go to whatismyip.com and give your friend the ip it shows. Then your friend just logs into your ip here:port also, I still didn't get a notification because you spelled my name wrong. Hehe.

Comment: @AidanMueller sorry, while I can configure my ports and his and set all of that up, there are still 2 issues. First it's all pointless if Minecraft starts listening on a network adaptor like 'Virtualbox VM network adaptor' or one of the many other network adaptors that don't have real hardware and represent 'other' things. No amount of connecting or port forwarding will fix that. 2nd: Soon I'll need to set this up with my 7yr old sister. Would you like to explain to her port forwarding an IPs?

Comment: @TomJNowell only the person hosting has to port forward. Another thing, are you in th same house on the same network? And why are you using virtual box?

Comment: @AidanMueller I'm a web developer, I use Virtualbox to run multiple OS' for testing without having to reboot. If it weren't a Virtualbox network adaptor it'd be VMWare or VirtualPC.

Comment: @AidanMueller and again, there's no point in port forwarding if Minecraft listens on a virtual internal network adaptor and not the internet exposed LAN network adaptor, which can and does happen, and is the core problem in my question. No amount of port forwarding and DMZ'ing will fix that, I could have 2 machines directly plugged into eachother with all the firewalls turned off and static IPs and it still wouldn't make a different if Minecraft decides to listen on the wrong adaptor

Comment: @AidanMueller think of minecraft as somebody shouting, and the client is someone with an ear listening for the shout. What your telling me is that I need to take the ear muffs off of the client. What I'm saying is that minecraft is shouting into an alternate universe, and the client will never hear it even with the most expensive microphones and listening devices ever invented.

Comment: @TomJNowell what I mean is why are you using virtual box if MC is cross platform?

Comment: @AidanMueller you misunderstand. Virtualbox is installed, I didn't say I was using it to run Minecraft, rather minecraft running natively is picking up the wrong network adaptor to listen on, an example being the virtualbox network adaptor. It's also happened with it picking up the LAN and not Hamachi and vice versa

Comment: @TomJNowell Are you on the same network as the person connecting to your world? And also, can you not disable the virtual box adaptor?

Comment: @AidanMueller  have done but there's nothing stopping Minecraft listening to local LAN instead of Hamachi LAN or vice versa

Comment: @AidanMueller and once again yes and no, I've had the issue when the other machine is on my local LAN **and** when it is not on my local LAN.

Comment: @AidanMueller I get the impression you believe this is a firewall or port forwarding issue, it is not. The program is not using the correct network adaptor to listen. For reference I can ping the IPs  with no issues with fast responses, I can also run a webserver on both machines, and load webpages from either machine. Contacting the machine is not an issue, making minecraft listen on the right network interface **is**

Answer (score 3):

This problem is likely caused by incorrect network adapter priority.

Danny Plughoeft described the process in XP; to do this in Windows 7, go to `Control Panel` → `View network status and tasks` under `Network and Internet`. In the left sidebar, click `Change adapter settings`, then press `ALT+N` to bring up the `Advanced` menu. Finally, choose `Advanced Settings`.

Then, under the `Adapters and Bindings` tab, select the Hamachi adapter under `Connections` and press the up button until it's at the top.

This should make Minecraft (and any other games) always try to use Hamachi whenever it's available.